# What word would best describe the term "With very little confidence"?

Tags: word-usage

What word would best describe the term "with very little confidence" ?

Comment: **timid** and certain synonyms. _timid_: showing a lack of courage or confidence; easily frightened. [ODO]

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/confident has several options.

Comment: Depending on context it could mean 'have very little trust in' as in "I asked my son to tidy his room with very little confidence that he would do it". We do need more context to be able to answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either [*diffident*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diffident) or [*hesitant*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hesitant). You can also [Google for `antonyms` of *confident*](https://www.google.com/#q=confident+antonym).